# Problems with Dockerbeats dashboard containerName field

Tags: docker, containers, kibana, dashboard, filebeat

I have dockerbeats set up on a local cluster that is running ELK stack and some other misc. dockers (all containers controlled via kubernetes). I set up the dashboard from Ingensi ([Ingensi dockerbeat Dashboard](https://github.com/Ingensi/beats-dashboards/tree/dockerbeat)) for kibana and ran into an issue with the containerNames field while setting up the graphs. Now, for context, my docker containers have names like these:

```
k8s_dockerbeats.79c42f90_dockerbeats-796n9_default_472faa11-1b3a-11e6-8bf4-28924a2bffbf_2832ea88
```

(as well as supporting containers for kubernetes with similar container names)  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvIUG.png
    k8s_POD.6d00e006_dockerbeats-796n9_default_472faa11-1b3a-11e6-8bf4-28924a2bffbf_3ddcfe44

When I set up the dashboard in kibana I get an issue where I get multiple containerNames from the same container. For example instead of a single containerName output I get the containerName split up into smaller segments:

```
k8s_dockerbeats
79c42f90_dockerbeats
796n9
28924a2bffbf_3ddcfe44
```

and so on...

I assume that the format of the container name is confusing the dashboard (maybe in the way that it parses the name information) and I could probably go around renaming every container to a more sensible name.

But before I do that, is there a way to configure the dashboard in such a way that I read in the entire container name string so that it does not break up like it does in the first image? (assuming I'll have to dig into the .json files from the repository mentioned above)

Thanks in advance if anyone answers this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the container name is being analyzed by Elasticsearch. You need to make sure that the container name field is marked as `not_analyzed` in the Elasticsearch index template. You can do this by installing the [index template](https://github.com/Ingensi/dockerbeat#elasticsearch-template) provided by Dockerbeat.

Marking the field as `not_analyzed` ensures that the data is not tokenized and it gets indexed as is. It will only be searchable by specifying the exact string.

You will need to delete your current indexes after installing the new index template in order to change the mappings.

Install the provided index template:

- `curl -XPUT 'http://elasticsearch:9200/_template/dockerbeat' -d@dockerbeat.template.json`

Delete your the existing indexes:

- `curl -XDELETE 'http://elasticsearch:9200/dockerbeat-*'`

You can view your current mappings by querying Elasticearch:

- `curl http://elasticsearch:9200/dockerbeat-*/_mapping`

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. (I did not know what the docker.template did before now)